# MS Access DB on network with multiple users

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access database on a network drive with a userform which has multiple users (All using at the same time)

The form runs an update-query which will add data into a raw data table.

Does anybody know how I can make this work if two(or more) users run the update query at the same time? I assume this has to be done using temporary tables...

Thanks,
James

Comment: have you split into a  front-end and back-end?

Comment: No I have not. Will try this. I am new here, would you like me to upvote you or something similar? I am not quite sure how I flag you as answering my question.

Comment: upvoting is at your discretion.

Comment: an update query modifying an existing row or an insert query adding a new one?  If inserting new rows, you should be fine.  If updating the same row, you'll need a method to determine the winner, but Access should still handle this by notifying the loser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to add some pages from my website to this discussion.

You want to split the MDB into a Front End MDB containing the queries, forms, reports, macros and modules with just the tables and relationships in the Back End MDB.  The FE is copied to each network users computer.   The FE MDB is linked to the tables in the back end MDB which resides on a server.    You make updates to the FE MDB and distribute them to the users, likely as an MDE.

See the ["Splitting your app into a front end and back end Tips"](http://tp://www.granite.ab.ca/access/splitapp/) page for more info.  See the free [Auto FE Updater](http://www.autofeupdater.com/) utility to make the distribution of new FEs relatively painless..   The utility also supports Terminal Server/Citrix quite nicely.  Also visit my [Access Performance FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm) page.

Comment: +1. Voting up because Tony is such an excellent resource for all things MS Access.

Comment: Mitch, Thanks for your kind words

Comment: just telling it how it is. I'd vote up 10 times if I could. Your site has helped me out many times over a decade!

Answer (score 4):

Access does not behave well if the entire database (front end forms plus backend database) is accessed by several users from a network share.

Try splitting into a front end (one on each client machine) and a single backend (tables) on the network share, and use linked tables in the front-end.

[How to manually split a Access database in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932)

[Information about query performance in an Access database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209126)

[Microsoft Access Performance Tips to Speed up Your Access Databases](http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/faster/)

Tony Toews' [Microsoft Access Performance FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm) is well worth reading.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. EDIT: It wont allow me to upvote you because I do not have any reputations. This has answered my question so would be grateful if somebody could upvote Mitch Wheat!

Comment: And of course don’t forget the excellent Access Auto FE updater at http://autofeupdater.com/ God I should be getting commission!

Comment: Also, it's not just splitting that's crucial, but giving each user an individual copy of the front end. Both of those are the most basic practices of any Access application deployment -- your app simply won't work reliably if you don't do those two things (splitting and giving an individual front end to each user).

Comment: Kevin,  I'd be happy to give you 100% of the revenue from the free downloads.  <smile>   And please email or phone me if you have any problems or suggestions.